# Cassandra unit spring - Launch an embedded Cassandra only once per test class

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, cassandraunit, embedded-cassandra

I am setting up integration tests for my spring-boot application using cassandra-unit-spring maven dependency. I am able to run my tests which invoke the spring-boot application which in turn accesses an in-memory embedded Cassandra database.

Below is the code for my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@CassandraDataSet(value = "cassandra/dbcreate.cql", keyspace = "test")
@EmbeddedCassandra
@SpringBootTest({"spring.data.cassandra.port=9142"})
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindById() {
        Token token = generateRandomToken();
        testRepository.insert(token);

        Optional<Token> tokenStored = testRepository.findById(token.getKey());

        compareReplayToken(token, tokenStored.get()); //This method does the assertions
    }
}
```

This single test invokes the embedded Cassandra and creates the keyspace and tables from the commands in the ***cassandra/dbcreate.cql*** file. After the test runs, the keyspace and tables are dropped.

Till now, it is fine. But, if I try to add multiple tests in this class, this approach creates the keyspace and tables at the beginning of each test and then drops them once the test runs.

And the dbcreate.cql file has a lot of commands to create multiple tables and when these commands run for each test, this makes my tests really slow.

Also, this problem multiplies when I try to have multiple such test classes.

Possible solution that I could think of is:

**Have a separate cql file for each test class that has limited cql commands concerned with that class only** - Again, this doesn't solve the problem of the database reset for each test in a single class

I want to run all my integration tests for a single launch of this embedded Cassandra and the tables and keyspace should be created and dropped only once for a fast execution

What should be the ideal solution for such a problem?
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!